# Code is working fine on DEV C++ but getting segmentation error on Hacker Rank's test case

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

I am getting a segmentation error on one of the Hacker Rank's test case while the other two cases are working fine. Even the same code is working fine in my system(using DEV C++) when I inserted the inputs same as the test case which is generating an error.
The problem is Priority Based Thread Scheduling.
Given below is the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct thread_node {
  char name[10];
  int priority;
  struct thread_node *next;
};
typedef struct thread_node thread_node;

struct priority_queue {
  thread_node *front, *rear;
};
typedef struct priority_queue priority_queue;

void enqueue(priority_queue *queue, thread_node *thread) {

  if(queue->rear == NULL){
      queue->front = queue->rear = thread;
      return;
  }
    thread_node *tempFront = queue->front;
    if(queue->rear->priority < thread->priority){
        queue->rear->next = thread;
        queue->rear = thread;
        
    }else{
        if(queue->front == queue->rear){
            thread->next = queue->rear;
            queue->front = thread ; return;
        }
        
        if(thread->priority >= queue->front->priority){
            while(thread->priority >= tempFront->next->priority && tempFront->priority != queue->rear->priority) 
            tempFront = tempFront->next;
            
            thread->next = tempFront->next;
            tempFront->next = thread;
        }
        
        if(thread->priority < queue->front->priority ){
            thread->next = queue->front;
            queue->front = thread; return;
        }
        
    }
}

thread_node* dequeue(priority_queue *queue) {
  thread_node* temp = queue->front;
  
  queue->front = queue->front->next;
  
  return(temp);
}


/*=======DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE BELOW =======*/

thread_node* create_node(char *thread_name, int thread_priority) {
  thread_node *thread;
  thread = (thread_node*)malloc(sizeof(thread_node));
  thread->priority = thread_priority;
  strcpy (thread->name, thread_name);
  thread->next = NULL;

  return thread;
}

//Get new queue
priority_queue* create_queue() {
  priority_queue *queue = (priority_queue*)malloc(sizeof(priority_queue));
  queue->front = NULL;
  queue->rear = NULL;

  return queue;
}

void display(thread_node *thread) {
        printf("%s %d", thread->name, thread->priority);
        printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
        int thread_count, thread_priority;
        char thread_name[10];

        priority_queue *queue = create_queue();

        scanf("%d", &thread_count);

        thread_node *thread[thread_count];

        //Input the Thread priority table and put it in queue.
        for (int index = 0; index < thread_count; index++) {
        scanf("%s %d",thread_name,&thread_priority);

        thread[index] = create_node(thread_name, thread_priority);

        enqueue(queue, thread[index]);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < thread_count; index++) {
                //dequeue will return threads
                display(dequeue(queue));
       }
}
```

INPUT:
10
Thread0 6
Thread1 4
Thread2 9
Thread3 1
Thread5 9
Thread6 2
Thread7 4
Thread8 3
Thread9 6
Thread10 2

Error is given below:
Segmentation Fault
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
queue->front = thread; return;

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Looks to me like nothing is protecting `tempFront` from becoming NULL while iterating through your list during `enqueue`.  Well, actually, undefined behavior might "protect" that because you're also not protecting against dereferencing a NULL `next` pointer.  Surely you can design just about any 3-value input that breaks this.

Comment: 10
Thread0 6
Thread1 4
Thread2 9
Thread3 1
Thread5 9
Thread6 2
Thread7 4
Thread8 3 
Thread9 6
Thread10 2 @RetiredNinja